# Get confusion matrix for 3 classes in keras model

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

so I have data like in the shape of (10000, 178, 178, 3) where I have 10000 samples and each has 3 different color channel(not the RGB one), where I have divided them into 3 classes like this, so I have 3 labels `0, 1 & 2`:

Importing libraries:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import regularizers
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization

from keras import optimizers
import keras
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
```

```
label = np.where((np.array(val) < 0.1), 0, np.where((np.array(val) < 0.2) ,1, 2))
```

One Hot Encoding:

```
def to_one_hot(y, num_class=3):
    results = numpy.zeros((len(y), num_class))
    for i, label in enumerate(y):
        results[i, label] = 1

    return results

y_train_vec = to_one_hot(label)
```

Splitting for training and testing:

```
rand_indices = np.random.permutation(len(data))
train_indices = rand_indices[0:7460]
valid_indices = rand_indices[7460:len(data)]

x_test = data_array[valid_indices, :]
y_test = y_train_vec[valid_indices, :].astype('float')

x_train = data_array[train_indices, :]
y_train = y_train_vec[train_indices, :].astype('float')
```

Then I'm using this Neural Network for training this dataset:

```
weight_decay = 1e-4
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (20,20), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=x_tr.shape[1:]))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (30,30), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

Then here I'm training it:

```
def lr_schedule(epoch):
    lrate = 0.001
    if epoch > 30:
        lrate = 0.0005
    elif epoch > 60:
        lrate = 0.0003        
    return lrate

batch_size = 128

opt_rms = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt_rms, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size, epochs=100, verbose=1,
                   callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)])
```

Now I want confusion matrix for 3 classes, I know how to do that for 2 classes like this, but can someone tell me how can I do same thing for 3 classes:

```
T=0.5
y_pred = model.predict(x_val)
y_pred_bool = y_pred>=T

confusion_matrix(y_val, y_pred_bool)
```

Comment: Please provide the necessary imports so that its clear where the methods you are using in your code come from. thanks!

Comment: @AkshaySehgal please check the updated code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you get the shape of `y_pred_bool` and perhaps post a few rows to see what it looks like?

In general though, if your target is stored in a single column (shape `(N,)`):

```py
# Libraries
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix

# Target and predictions in (N,) shape
y_true = np.array([0, 1, 2])
y_pred = np.array([0, 1, 1])

# Get confusion matrix
confusion_matrix(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
> array([[1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0]])
```

You can use `sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix` if your target and predicted labels are encoded as indicator columns. This will yield one confusion matrix for each class in one-vs-rest fashion. For example:

```py
# Libraries
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix

# Target and predictions in (N, 3) shape
y_true = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
y_pred = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]])

# Get confusion matrix for each class 
multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
> array([[[2, 0],
          [0, 1]],

         [[1, 1],
          [0, 1]],

         [[2, 0],
          [1, 0]]])
```

Comment: hey sorry for late response, I was sick. Here's the output of my y_pred:

```array([[7.3365694e-01, 2.3474902e-01, 3.1593997e-02],
       [3.1977770e-01, 6.1781120e-01, 6.2411133e-02],
       [6.8967247e-01, 1.8431199e-01, 1.2601557e-01],
       ...,
       [2.8589216e-01, 7.0550179e-01, 8.6060567e-03],
       [9.8009664e-01, 1.9454861e-02, 4.4847900e-04],
       [5.3596318e-01, 4.6394366e-01, 9.3131493e-05]], dtype=float32)```

Comment: and this the shape of my y_pred_bool: ```(2487, 3)``` where 2487 are no of test records